# ANTLR: How to store both tokens and tree nodes in the same AST?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Given the following grammar:

```
 statement : START value_list;
 value_list : LEFT_PARENTHESIS element += value (COMMA element += value)* RIGHT_PARENTHESIS -> ^(LIST $element+);
 value : NUMBER | STRING | value_list;
 START : 'START';
 LEFT_PARENTHESIS : '(';
 RIGHT_PARENTHESIS : ')';
 COMMA : ',';
 NUMBER : ('0'..'9')+;
 STRING : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
```

How can one store COMMA in the AST? In other words, if one tries the following:

```
 value_list : LEFT_PARENTHESIS element += value (element += COMMA element += value)* RIGHT_PARENTHESIS -> ^(LIST $element+);
```

... it will give the following error:

```
 error(125): grammar.g:2:75: label element type mismatch with previous definition: token-list!=rule-list
```

Any hints on how to solve this issue? Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards,

TJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you can either add tree nodes in the `element` list or tokens, not both at the same time. Since you need to mix the two together, the list needs to contain tree nodes and you'll have to transform the token elements to tree nodes.

#### Solution 1:

If you want to go the generic `element +=` way, the easiest fix is probably wrapping the lexer token in a subtree using a simple rule:

```
comma: COMMA;
```

This way, if you use `comma` in your rule with rewrite, the rewrite rule will get a `nil` tree with a token instead of getting the token directly.

#### Solution 2:

Wrap the inside of the parentheses in a separate rule without rewriting the tree, then use it in the original rule with rewrite:

```
values : value (COMMA value)*;

value_list : LEFT_PARENTHESIS vals = values RIGHT_PARENTHESIS -> ^(LIST $vals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to not use the token list at all and simply iterate over the tree nodes when you need the elements. This totally trivial and the most flexible solution.